# Работа с текстовым файлом (запись/чтение) - C++

Tags: c++

Задали сделать программу, которая должна создавать файл, а потом совершать его чтение. Само задание: "Чемпионат города по футболу проводится по 2 группам: сильная (8 команд) и слабая (8 команд). Замещение мест в сильной группе проводится по результатам переходного турнира, в котором участвуют 3 худших команды из сильной группы и 3 лучших из слабой. Составить список команд-участниц переходного турнира, если данные о командах хранятся в файле в виде названия команды, наименования организации, за которую выступает команда, и количества очков." Половину задания я уже сделал. Будьте добры, помогите дописать программу, ибо в интернете не очень много информации. Буду очень благодарен за помощь.
Вот код :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
    struct gamers
    {
        char Name[30];
        int coin;
        int status;
    };
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    int sap;
    cout << "Введите количество футбольных команд : ";
    cin >> sap;
    gamers *pas = new gamers[sap];
    for(int i(0); i < sap; i++)
    {
        cin.sync();
        cout << "Введите название команды:";
        cin.getline(pas[i].Name,30);
        cout << "Введите количество очков команды " << pas[i].Name << ":";
        cin >> pas[i].coin;
        cout << "К какой группе относится команда " << pas[i].Name << " (1-сильная,2-слабая):";
        cin >> pas[i].status;
        cin.get();
        system("cls");
    }
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("cppstudio.txt");
    for(int i(0); i < sap; i++)
    { 
        outfile << pas[i].Name << '\t' << pas[i].coin << '\t' << pas[i].status << '\n';
    }
    outfile.close();
    delete [] pas;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: SO - это не форум, а вопросно-ответная система, регулируемая пользователями. А Вам стоит указать, что сделано и что конкретно не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Заведите два массива ([vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)): один для с сильными командами и один с слабыми. Заполните массивы данными с помощью метода `push_back` класса `vector`.Далее вы эти вектора сортируете с помощью [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/?kw=sort) по количеству очков. Наконец остается вывести 3 последних элемента первого массива и 3 первых элемента 2-го. Все!

Answer (score 0):

Для этой задачи следовало бы создать класс который описывает команду и хранить их в листе. И использовать бинарные файлы произвольного доступа, в которые бы записывались эти классы. И легче было бы доставать команды 3 с начала и 3 с конца. Едиснтвенный минус это нельзя редактировать файл вручную.

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой код у меня остался с начальных курсов, из одного файла считывает построчно список избирателей, помещает его в массив строк, сортирует его по алфавиту и выводит во второй файл. Может чем то пригодится:

```
void main(int N, char** f)
{ int i,j,n=0;
string buf;
ifstream in("Voter_1.txt");
ofstream out("Voter_2.txt");
while (getline(in,buf)) n++;
printf("n = %d \n",n);
rewind(in);
string* S= new string[n];
for (i=0;i<n;i++) getline(in,S[i]);// с этого момента со списком можно работать как с обычным массивом строк, к примеру, который можно разбить на массив из 3х слов - название, очки и группа.
for (i=0;i<n-1;i++)
for (j=0;j<n-1;j++) if (S[j]>S[j+1]) swp(S[j],S[j+1]);
for (i=0;i<n;i++) out << S[i] << endl;
delete[] S;
puts("$$$$$$$$ CHA CHING $$$$$$$$");
pause;
}
```